# How to prevent an element from appearing under a parent schema?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I have some slightly awkward markup and need to reference some elements from a separate container, and prevent those elements from appearing under the parent in their hierarchy. How can I do this?

Here's my (simplified) markup:

```html
<body itemscope itemtype='https://schema.org/AboutPage'>
  <div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ProfessionalService">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tab-emp1"><img id="photo-emp1" itemprop="image" src="..."/></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-emp2"><img id="photo-emp2" itemprop="image" src="..."/></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-emp3"><img id="photo-emp3" itemprop="image" src="..."/></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-emp4"><img id="photo-emp4" itemprop="image" src="..."/></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-emp1" itemprop="employee" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person"
         itemref="photo-emp1">
      <h1 itemprop="name">John Doe</h1>
      <h2 itemprop="jobTitle">Vice President, Finance</h2>
      <div itemprop="description">John is...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-emp2" itemprop="employee" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person"
         itemref="photo-emp2">
      <h1 itemprop="name">Jane Roe</h1>
      <h2 itemprop="jobTitle">Vice President, Operations</h2>
      <div itemprop="description">Jane is...</div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

The structure is required for a tab control, so I can't rearrange the markup.

The `itemref` attribute on the `Person` correctly drags the image 'under' the `https://schema.org/Person` node.

However, the `image` elements ALSO appear as properties under the `https://schema.org/ProfessionalService` node, which is not correct or desired.

How can I keep the `image` elements in their current location, reference them under `Person`, but **prevent them** from appearing under `ProfessionalService`?

Comment: Can you not Test for ItemType, ie `if itemtype = Professional Service and itemprop = employee then //remove img tags else //show image tags`?

Comment: no, the image tags need to be there in all cases -- they need to be referenced by the Person containers. But because the image elements are outside the person container, and underneath the ProfessionalService container, they look like they're properties of BOTH Person (correct) and ProfessionalService (incorrect).

Comment: What about making Professional Service a Property of Person?  Does each Person perform a Service, or have you got some that do none? `itemprop="photo" img src=...`  I see what your going for, but either way you've got to move something

Comment: Can’t you start the `div` with `ProfessionalService` after the image list (or add an additional `div`)?

Comment: @unor -- I can do that, but then I have another schema a level above it, and the images now become itemprops of that schema. Right now we've removed all the parent schemata, but I'd like to see if I can retain them -- and for that I need to 'hide' the itemprop from the schema it's nested in.

Comment: @eyoung100 -- I might be able to, but 1) my SEO expert has asked me to mark it up such that Person is a child of ProfessionalService and 2) I'd like to know iof there's an answer to the general problem. `itemref` solves half of  it -- including an element that's outside of the natural nesting structure -- but not the other half -- hiding it from the parent schema it's naturally nested in. Even if I could solve the current case otherwise, I can see having another variant of the problem in future, esp because we use tab controls that require this sort of markup.

Comment: Soapbox Warning:  It amazes me that so called experts dont get the point that you don't mess w/ data structure after you've filled it with data, i.e you don't add a foreign key to a database after the table is full... End Soapbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `itemscope` attribute to the `ul` element. You'll get an extra, disconnected, item, but the images will no longer be part of the ProfessionalService item.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! In retrospect, this makes sense -- of course that's what we're saying when we declare `itemscope`. I don't like the extra disconnected item, but it's far better than having incorrect and unrelated children under a parent scope. (We're also starting to look at the JSON format for this stuff -- we get data duplication (boo), but we get a clearer representation of the metadata, and have complete control over the structure. But while we're still using the markup approach, this goes a long way to making it work. Thanks!